# How to change UIBarButtonItem style?

Tags: iphone, coding-style, uibarbuttonitem

I try to change the style of a UIBarButtonItem when a user select a row in a tableView

I use it:
[btnValided setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
[btnValided setEnabled:YES];

But it's not good (setEnabled is good)

Have an idea?

Thanx for help :)

Comment: I need to use  [btnValided setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];

Comment: make sure btnValided is a UIBarButtonItem, and you still didn't tell whats you problem, maybe show us some sample code or screenshots whats the result and what it should be

Comment: I have the same issue. The button will not change style.

Answer (score 1):

I would release the unwanted old item and alloc and init a new one, and then add it to the same place.

Comment: I don't think its the right way to complete remove a button and create a new one, only to change the style. Apart that it cost more memory and cpu time you have to re-set all actions etc.

Comment: @iPortable: good point on CPU overheads. I didn't think of it. but delete and redo is always an option, especially when we cannot make it with conventional methods :-)

Answer (score 0):

what you exactly want to do? a tick button?

you can specify your own image if you like, one image for styleDefault and one image for styleHighlighted (or selected?) whatever you like.